# Arc length of a curve bounding from below a Fourier series

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series, arc-length, parsevals-identity

Assume $\gamma $ is a $C^1$ closed curve in the complex plane whose length is $2\pi$,and consider all its possible regular parametrization throught a parameter $t \in [0,2\pi]$

Let $\gamma(t)$ one of these parametrizations and let $\gamma(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n  e^{itn}$
its fourier series. Prove that

$\sum _{n= -\infty}^{\infty}|a_n|^2n^2 \geq \ 1$

and equality holds if and only if the parametrization is the one using arc length as parameter.

It is clear that I have to derive the fourier series and then use parseval identity but I do not know how to conclude.   I would like a full solution to this problem.

Comment: If I remember correctly, a proof is included in Dacorogna's *Introduction to the Calculus of Variations*. ;-)

Comment: There is no the proof of the statement I am trying to prove. I think,indeed , I should change the title to my question which is a bit misleading

Comment: Your question is missing something. $\gamma(t) = \frac{1}{100} e^{it}$ is a regular parametrization of a tiny circle. You have that the sum desired is equal to exactly $10^{-4} < 1$. There seems to be a condition on $\gamma$ that you are missing.

Comment: you are so right I am editing right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By $||\cdot||$ I mean the $L^2[0,2\pi]$ norm.

$$\sum n^2|a_n|^2=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|\gamma'(t)|^2dt=\frac{1}{2\pi}||\gamma'||^2\ge^a\frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{\langle \gamma',1\rangle^2}{||1||^2}= \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\int_0^{2\pi}|\gamma'(t)|dt\right)^2=\frac{1}{4\pi^2}l(\gamma)^2=1$$

- a: By Cauchy-Schwarz